# JavaScript from page 195 of Stoyan Stefanov Object Oriented JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Using the code below, taken from page 95 of Stoyan Stefanov`s Object Oriented JavaScript, if you call

```
var my = new Triangle(5, 10);
 my.toString()
```

You get this result.

```
 "shape, 2D shape, Triangle"
```

My question relates to the first function (function Shape) in this code.

1) I know what `length` property normally does, but why is it important in this `function Shape` in the code `result[result.length]`.  If the code is returning the array of strings "shape, 2D shape, Triangle", where is it taking the length of the names and what is it doing with the length of the names?

2) Can you please explain (using plain language) what the program is saying with `result[result.length]`? i.e. having a result inside a result.

Thanks

```
function Shape(){}
// augment prototype
Shape.prototype.name = 'shape';
Shape.prototype.toString = function(){
var result = [];
if (this.constructor.uber) {
result[result.length] = this.constructor.uber.toString();
}
result[result.length] = this.name;
return result.join(', ');
};


function TwoDShape(){}
// take care of inheritance
var F = function(){};
F.prototype = Shape.prototype;
TwoDShape.prototype = new F();
TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;
TwoDShape.uber = Shape.prototype;
// augment prototype
TwoDShape.prototype.name = '2D shape';

function Triangle(side, height) {
this.side = side;
this.height = height;
}
// take care of inheritance
var F = function(){};
F.prototype = TwoDShape.prototype;
Triangle.prototype = new F();
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;
Triangle.uber = TwoDShape.prototype;
// augment prototype
Triangle.prototype.name = 'Triangle';
Triangle.prototype.getArea = function(){return this.side * this.height / 2;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result[result.length] = this.name;
```

This is essentially a way to add a new piece to the array at the next position available (offset forward).

Arrays in Javascript start with 0, so when the first array piece is added, it will in effect do this:

```
result = [];

// result is empty, so result.length == 0
result[0] = this.name;
```

Then, when the next toString() method is called, it will take the result array "length" (count) and create a new array piece at that index:

```
// result has one piece, so result.length == 1
result[1] = this.name;
```

Then, when the next toString() method is called, it will again take the result array "length" (count) and create a new array piece at that index:

```
// result has two pieces, so result.length == 2
result[2] = this.name;
```

So that you have an array with three pieces, using indices of 0, 1, 2, or the count of the result array pieces at the moment the array piece was added.

Answer (score 1):

The code assumes that `result` is going to be an array with consecutive integer keys. Such an array with `length` items is going to have indexes from 0 to `length - 1`. So by setting `result[result.length] = something`, what happens is that you add an item to that array, and the index for the new item is one higher than the previously last index.

In effect, it adds one item to the array while keeping the index numbering continuous, without leaving any empty spaces between the item indexes.

Answer (score 0):

An array's length property is always the highest index plus 1, so adding an item at array[array.length] adds an item at the end of the array.

It's equivalent to array.push(...) and sometimes preferred because some (very) old browsers don't have a push method and sometimes it's faster (and sometimes it's slower).